# Наклон при движении transform

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3

Объект движется по планке,с помощью кода

```
$('#telo').css('transform', 'translate(350px,0)');
```

Хочу чтобы он чуть наклонялся в начале движения,а в конце обратно ровным был,пытался сразу 2 навесить,

```
$('#telo').css('transform', 'translate(350px,0)');
$('#telo').css('transform', 'rotate(15deg)');
```

В этой ситуации сначала происходит наклон,а движения нет

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/h3o5Lwkq/1/

Comment: Вам нужно воспользоваться анимацией...либо css либо jquery https://jsfiddle.net/h3o5Lwkq/3/

Comment: Анимацией не получится,значение не всегда заранее известно, на которое будет совершено перемещение.А если jquery метод animate.он иногда подлагивает,нету плавности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убрать вторую трансформацию в функцию и вызывать её по таймеру.

```
function run() {
  $('#telo').css('transform', 'translate(350px,0)');
}

$("#btn1").click(function(){
  $('#telo').css('transform', 'rotate(15deg)');
  setTimeout(run, 250);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/gfs0cwet/

Comment: Спасибо,то что надо

Comment: @zkolya Удобно, что объект сам выпрямляется обратно и это не надо специально описывать. 
Если добавить к div#telo `  transform-origin: 50% 95% 0;`, то объект не повернётся вокруг центра, а наклонится вперёд. 
И забавно, что теперь кнопку можно нажимать повторно. Если установить таймер на 800 миллисекунд, то объект [успевает вернуться на старт](https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/gfs0cwet/9/).

Comment: Спасибо,это действительно,очень круто ,а можно ли сделать так,чтоб он в конце чуть назад отклонялся и обратно ровно,типо эффект остановки?

Comment: @zkolya Вариант 1. Через [transition-timing-function](https://webref.ru/css/transition-timing-function) задать [кривую Безье](http://cubic-bezier.com/#.3,-0.4,.9,1.2) так, чтобы анимация на старте отступала в обратную сторону, а на финише пролетала мимо и возвращалась. Посмотрите обновлённый https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/gfs0cwet/ Я добавил кривую Безье и увеличил наклон объекта для наглядности. И через анимация по окончании возвращается на старт, кнопку можно жать повторно.

Comment: Вариант 2. Всё таки через анимацию. https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/Lpb5hjo9/

Comment: Очень круто,спасибо,предельно благодарен Вам!